# Perl - Transforming an anonymous array

Tags: perl

I can manipulate a single array element and add a reference to the array as a value in a hash. Easy. For example, this achieves the desired result:

```
# split the line into an array
my @array = split;

# convert the second element from hex to dec
$array[1] = hex($array[1]);

# now add the array to a hash
$hash{$name}{ ++$count{$name} } = \@array;
```

My question: Is it possible to do the same thing using an anonymous array? I can get close by doing the following:

```
$hash{$name}{ ++$count{$name} } = [ split ];
```

However, this doesn't manipulate the second index (convert hex to dec) of the anonymous array. If it can be done, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is this

```
my $array = [ split ];

$array->[1] = hex($array->[1]);

$hash{$name}{ ++$count{$name} } = $array;
```

But that may not be what you mean.

Also, rather than using sequential numbered hash keys you would probably be better off using a hash of arrays, like this

```
my $array = [ split ];

$array->[1] = hex($array->[1]);

push @{ $hash{$name} }, $array;
```

You need a way to access the array to say what you want to modify, but you could modify it after pushing it onto the hash, like this:

```
push @{ $hash{$name} }, [split];
$hash{$name}[-1][1] = hex($hash{$name}[-1][1]);
```

although that's really not very nice. Or you could

```
push @{ $hash{$name} }, do {
    my @array = [split];
    $array[1] = hex($array[1]);
    \@array;
};
```

or even

```
for ([split]) {
    $_->[1] = hex($_->[1]);
    push @{ $hash{$name} }, $_;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you Borodin. I guess my question was - can `$array` also be anonymous? I can see now that it can't be. I will also implement you're HoA suggestion. Cheers.

Comment: $array is a reference to an anonymous array; does that help?  You *could* do `$hash{$name}{ ++$count{$name} } = map [$_->[0], hex($_->[1]), @$_[2..$#$_]], [split];` but that would be silly

Comment: here is another variation on this theme: `$hash{$name}{ ++$count{$name} } = (map { $_->[1] = hex($_->[1]); $_ } ([split]))[0];`

Comment: oh, oops, you are right, the `()[0]` is needed around the map (or parens around `$hash{$name}{++$count{$name}}` to make it a list assignment)

Comment: All imran and ysth's options do is store the array reference in `$_` instead of an explicit `$array`.